# Is there a short form of "greater than or equal to" (≥)

Tags: spoken-english, mathematics, reading-aloud

From [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38287/do-we-say-is-greater-or-equal-to-or-is-greater-or-equal-than) I know that when mixing "greater than" (>) and "equal to" (=) the correct expression to say is "greater than or equal to"(>=). However, I remember that my math teacher, when writing on the blackboard, always spoke out loudly (in German) what he was writing, e.g. when writing `5x >= 2y`, he would have said "fünf x **größer gleich** 2 y", which is, afaik, common when speaking out this operator in German.

I can't imagine that when speaking about this mathemathical formula in English you would say "five x **greater than or equal to** 2 y". Is it commonly accepted to *say* something like "five x **greater equal** two y"?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE! If you had any questions about the policies of our community, you might find answers in [the help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) or you can just start by taking a [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: In more informal situations you can say "at least". But I've never heard anything but the full expression in mathematics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In English, one reads “5​*x* ≥ 2​*y*” aloud as:

> Five ex **is greater than or equal to** two wye.

The **is** and **or** make the sentence literally true by the conventions of ordinary English.

It *is* quite a mouthful to say. Occasionally I hear people say “greater than equal” to hurry, omitting “is”, “or”, and “to”, but holding “than” a little long to give equal time to each of the three words. More commonly, though, people just get very good at saying “is greater than or equal to” very quickly.

Answer (score 8):

Among mathematicians, it is common to use the phrase ***at least*** in this context:  `5x >= 2y` could be read as *five x is **at least** two y*.  Note that you still need the verb *is*.  For `<=`, you can use *at most*.

I am not sure whether this usage would be immediately clear to a non-techical audience.

You could also say *five x is **not less than** two y*, or perhaps ***no less than***.  This usage seems to be common in legal writing.

(Pedantic nitpick: to a mathematician, `>=` and `<=` are not *operators* but *relations*.)

Comment: I don't know whether it's used in English, but a possible way to shorten the reading is to agree with the audience that >= is read as "greater than" and > is read as "strictly greater than".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that is the most practical way of reading this comparison aloud. By the way: Opposing mathemathics, in computer sciences `>=` and `<=` are operators (because a comparison  operation yields a result there, i.e. _true_ or _false_)